# Did Jesus or G-d come in a vision to Ananias?

Tags: acts

I am curious to know if there is a contradiction here?

**In Acts 9**

1. Ananias is a Disciple of Jesus.
2. There is no mention of him being a devout Jew
3. Lord[Jesus] talks to Ananias in a vision
4. Lord[Jesus] has a plan to use Paul for preaching to all people

**In Acts 22**

1. Ananias is a devout observer of the law and respected by all the Jews (could be a disciple as well)
2. There is no mention of who came to Ananias in a vision.
3. Ananias is told that the G-d of Abraham has a plan to use Paul for preaching to all people.

> **Acts 9:10** In Damascus there was a **disciple** named Ananias. The Lord called to him in a vision, “Ananias!”  “Yes, Lord,” he answered. ***11*** The **Lord** told him, “Go to the house of Judas on Straight Street and ask for a man from Tarsus named Saul, for he is praying. ***12*** In a vision he has seen a man named Ananias come and place his hands on him to restore his sight.” ***15*** But the Lord said to Ananias, “Go! This man is my chosen instrument to proclaim my name to the Gentiles and their kings and to the people of Israel. ***16*** I will show him how much he must suffer for my name.”

> **Acts 22:12** “A man named Ananias came to see me. He was a **devout observer of the law** and highly respected by all the Jews living there. 13 He stood beside me and said, ‘Brother Saul, receive your sight!’ And at that very moment, I was able to see him. 14 “Then he said: ‘The **God of our ancestors** has chosen you to know his will and to see the Righteous One and to hear words from his mouth. 15 You will be his witness to all people of what you have seen and heard. 16 And now what are you waiting for? Get up, be baptized, and wash your sins away, calling on his name.’

Comment: Are you suggesting the passages are contradictory? Please edit this to explain in more detail.

Comment: @curiousdannii done.

Comment: @Yeddu The question is not asked in a valid form, for in this formulation it precludes that Jesus is God. “Lord” whom Ananias listens and obeyed is not angel, but God, and this God is Jesus. All angels are servants, while Jesus is  Lord, of the same authority as Lord the Father.

Comment: Sorry, I am rewording my earlier comment. I meant that as per trinity doctrine, there are 3 distinct persons in one being when we refer to any of the persons we refer to them as G-d(Father), Son, Holy Spirit.

Comment: Your nomenclature is not in accord with what is usually referred to as 'trinity doctrine'. Trinitarian doctrine would record God : Father, Son and Holy Spirit. Not as you have indicated with your bracket attached.

Comment: Noted Nijel. Not familiar with the doctrine yet,

Comment: Acts 22:14 says nothing about a vision. *The God of our ancestors has chosen you* is not the same as *the God of our ancestors has appeared to you*.

Answer (score 2):

Acts 9:

> 1Meanwhile, Saul was still breathing out murderous threats against the disciples of the **Lord**.

> 5 “Who are You, **Lord**?” Saul asked.
> “I am **Jesus**, whom you are persecuting,” He replied.

> 10 In Damascus there was a disciple named Ananias. The **Lord** spoke to him in a **vision**, “Ananias!”
>
> “Here I am, **Lord**,” he answered.
>
> 11 “Get up!” the **Lord** told him.

> 13 But Ananias answered, “**Lord**, many people have told me about this man and all the harm he has done to Your saints in Jerusalem.

> 15“Go!” said the **Lord**. “This man is My chosen instrument to carry My name before the Gentiles and their kings, and before the people of Israel.

> 17 So Ananias went to the house, and when he arrived, he placed his hands on Saul. “Brother Saul,” he said, “the **Lord Jesus**, who appeared to you on the road as you were coming here, has sent me so that you may see again and be filled with the Holy Spirit.”

All the references here point to Jesus as the Lord.

Did Jesus or G-d come in a vision to Ananias?

From the texts as well as the context, according to point of view of Ananias, it was Jesus who spoke to Ananias in a vision.

Now let's switch text to an additional account by Paul in Acts 22:

> 12 “A man named Ananias came to see me. He was a devout observer of the law and highly respected by all the Jews living there. 13 He stood beside me and said, ‘Brother Saul, receive your sight!’ And at that very moment, I was able to see him. 14 “Then he said: ‘**The God of our ancestors** has chosen you to know his will and to see the Righteous One and to hear words from his mouth. 15 You will be his witness to all people of what you have seen and heard. 16 And now what are you waiting for? Get up, be baptized, and wash your sins away, calling on his name.’

Paul met Ananias. Paul said that Ananias said that "the God of our ancestors has chosen you". Paul didn't say that Jesus did not come to Ananias in a vision.

Comment: Tony, Please see ***Acts 22*** narration of Paul about what Ananias said

Comment: Good point. I added. Ask again if further questions.

Comment: So G-d did not say this and that Paul probably was under stress (remember the situation was quite hostile) right?

Comment: What exactly did G-d not say?

Comment: With regard to Acts 22, I meant so G-d did not say it but Jesus said it to Ananias.

Comment: Right. That's how I interpret it. I try to stick to the words of the text as much as possible.

Comment: In all fairness, these issues are possible as Luke was not there in either of the events.

Comment: Right. Many things are possible. I look for the ones with the highest probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Let us be very clear about what the two passages are saying:

**Acts 9:17** - So Ananias went to the house, and when he arrived, he placed his hands on Saul. “Brother Saul,” he said, “the **Lord Jesus**, who appeared to you on the road as you were coming here, has sent me so that you may see again and be filled with the Holy Spirit.”

Thus, it was actually Jesus who appeared to Paul and who sent Ananias to Paul.  This confirms the Jesus has the title "Lord" as used in V10, 11, 13, 15, etc.

**Acts 22:14-16** - Then he [Ananias] said [to Paul], ‘The God of our fathers has appointed you to know His will, and to see the Righteous One, and to hear His voice. You will be His witness to everyone of what you have seen and heard. And now what are you waiting for? Get up, be baptized, and wash your sins away, calling on His name.’

Thus, it is God who appointed Paul to be an apostle to the Gentiles and who sent Ananias to Paul to heal him.

The herculean endeavors of some to make a fine distinction that Jesus did this but the Father did that here are unavailing - the simple comparison of these two passages shows that Paul believed that Jesus was part of the Godhead.

Comment: Luke under inspiration deliberately conflates Jesus with Lord and God in order to dispel any doubt that Jesus was the God of their forefathers. In Stephen’s speech Luke points out that it was the Angel that spoke to Moses whereas they OT would read God spoke to Moses. It’s so heartwarming to learn about one’s creator God Jesus

Comment: @Dottard, I am not here to defy anyone's beliefs, I am not on an intellectual pursuit, I am not trying to find fault with the Greek text, I am not making any herculean efforts to prove anything, I am seeking the truth to make sure I don't believe & worship anyone or anything as god except the G-d of Abraham my creator. I am old and want to be with G-d when I die. Every time the Israelites went after other god’s they were punished. I ask G-d every day to help me understand who this Jesus is and if I need to believe in him to come to my G-d. Please consider this and try help if you can.

Comment: @Nihil Sine Deo, it could be just a mistake as well.

Comment: @Yeddu - I am not suggesting you make herculean efforts - I was alluding some others who try to ignore Bible evidence.

Comment: @Dottard, Thank you for understanding. I have been a Christian for 53 years done with providing for me and my family and all I am looking forward to is be with G-d. I am losing my faith as there are too many issues in 1. Tying it back to Tanakh(what G-d) said, 2. I am seeing conflicts between Tanakh and the greek text. 3. These clashes null out what G-d said as they are not perfect. 4. To me it is a matter of Hell or Heaven, Please see all my questions, they are all focussed on these points. Please do try to help. You seem to be very well studied in these areas I have concerns. G-d Bless you.

Comment: @Yeddu - I think I have proffered an answer to most of your questions.

Comment: @Dottard, Yes. Thank you

Comment: @Yeddu what do you mean a mistake? What kind of mistake?

Comment: @Nihil Sine Deo, I am saying that Luke could have made a mistake and said god instead of Jesus.

Comment: @Yeddu not even likely, Luke does the same thing for the Holy Spirit in Acts. This is intentional and deliberate language. Entirely consistent with OT understanding of God being three persons. Granted it’s also in the spirit of OT revelation whereby two texts speaking about the same person would conflate either the Spirit of the Lord and later just God, or the Angel of the Lord and then it would just read God. It’s all over the OT and Luke was doing the exact same thing.

Comment: Why do you use conflate as opposed to equate. Do that and you have no problem.